# why did the error "The hostname this node should have according to the configuration does not match a local interface" occur?

Tags: mysql, database

Host1:

ip: 42.a1.b1.c1 (in configuration file, a1,b1,c1 will be replaced by real values.)

mysql-cluster-community-server, mysql-cluster-community-management-server and mysql-cluster-community-data-node are all installed on this host.

Host2:

ip: 119.a2.b2.c2 (in configuration file, a2,b2,c2 will be replaced by real values.)

Both mysql-cluster-community-server and mysql-cluster-community-data-node are installed on this host.

All mysql-cluster-* softwares on both hosts didn't start.

---

`cat /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini` on host1 outputs:

```
[ndbd default]
# Options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:
NoOfReplicas=1    # Number of fragment replicas
DataMemory=80M    # How much memory to allocate for data storage
IndexMemory=18M   # How much memory to allocate for index storage
                  # For DataMemory and IndexMemory, we have used the
                  # default values. Since the "world" database takes up
                  # only about 500KB, this should be more than enough for
                  # this example NDB Cluster setup.
                  # NOTE: IndexMemory is deprecated in NDB 7.6 and later; in
                  # these versions, resources for all data and indexes are
                  # allocated by DataMemory and any that are set for IndexMemory
                  # are added to the DataMemory resource pool
ServerPort=2202   # This the default value; however, you can use any
                  # port that is free for all the hosts in the cluster
                  # Note1: It is recommended that you do not specify the port
                  # number at all and simply allow the default value to be used
                  # instead
                  # Note2: The port was formerly specified using the PortNumber
                  # TCP parameter; this parameter is no longer available in NDB
                  # Cluster 7.5.

[ndb_mgmd]
# Management process options:
HostName=42.a1.b1.c1           # Hostname or IP address of management node
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for management node log files

#[ndbd]
#Options for data node "A":
                                # (one [ndbd] section per data node)
#HostName=42.a1.b1.c1           # Hostname or IP address
#NodeId=2                        # Node ID for this data node
#DataDir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files

[ndbd]
#Options for data node "B":

HostName=119.a2.b2.c2         # Hostname or IP address
NodeId=3                        # Node ID for this data node
DataDir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files

[mysqld]
#SQL node options:
HostName=119.a2.b2.c2           # Hostname or IP address
                                # (additional mysqld connections can be
                                # specified for this node for various
                                # purposes such as running ndb_restore)
```

`ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini --ndb-nodeid=1` on host1 outpus:

```
MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.7.32 ndb-7.6.16
2020-11-07 16:35:20 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- at line 5: [DB] IndexMemory is deprecated, will use Number bytes on each ndbd(DB) node allocated for storing indexes instead
2020-11-07 16:35:20 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- The hostname this node should have according to the configuration does not match a local interface. Attempt to bind '42.a1.b1.c1' failed with error: 99 'Cannot assign requested address'
```

why did the error "The hostname this node should have according to the configuration does not match a local interface" occur?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like the IP is not reachable. Van you try to Ping the IP from your database server?

Comment: @Jens Thanks. I've tried `curl 42.a1.b1.c1` on host1 and since I've started nginx so I get the default index.html content.. I get the same result on host2.

Answer (score 0):

Happen because /etc/hosts has not been loaded in ram at boot time when your ndb service load.
i do resolve this on my case just adding 5 sec pause into the service script.

detail:
[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/bin/sleep 5